# Overview of camel endpoints?

Tags: java, apache-camel, wildfly-8

I have deployed my camel integration projects (WAR) on a JBoss Wildfly application server.

I was wondering if there is a way to see what endpoints are available and what the URL's are?

In a similiar way as i can log into the administration console under Wildfly and select web services to get an overview of what is deployed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have `JMX` enabled on your camel context, then you can view a list of endpoints via `jconsole`, as you can see from:

[image: Camel JConsole]

`JMX` is on by default according to the [camel site](http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html) but if you've somehow disabled it, adding:

```
<jmxAgent id="agent" disabled="false"/>
```

to your `<camelContext>` element should be enough to re-enable it.

Comment: Hi Andrew - Thanks, I was not aware of this. It helps me in my debugging. I am still missing a place where i can get the actual web service endpoints. For example service X is located here: http://localhost:8080/webservice1/get?wsdl Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is also hawtio which is a web console to manage Java stuff, and it has plugins for Apache Camel, JBoss, and others too.

You could then install hawtio in wildfly, and then see your Camel routes / endpoints and whatnot

- http://hawt.io/